# Override Apache Environment Variables

Tags: apache

I'm wondering if it's possible to override an Apache environment variable with another? Background is that I'm using a load balancer, which has the SSL, and so checking the `HTTPS` environment variable doesn't work, I instead need to check `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO`. I could handle this in my code, but I'm wondering if there is a way to set the `HTTPS` environment variable to the value of `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` at the Apache level.

Thanks!